# Is this Scala / Functional Programming pattern to avoid OOP classes, an official design pattern? Does it have a name?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, dependency-injection, functional-programming, implicit

Classes in OOP couple variables to methods via a scope, thus making refactors painful as we cannot easily move methods from one place into another.  The entire dependency graph, with initialisation, of the class must be moved with the method somehow.  A common "solution" in OOP is dependency injection frameworks.

E.g. in OOP

```
class Foo(client: Client) {
  def dumbCouplingOfMethodToScope: Unit = client.send("hello world")
}
```

In Scala the solution to this is to use implicit parameters, usually called a "Context". E.g.

```
object Foo {
  def methodNotDependOnScope(client: Client): Unit = client.send("hello world")
}
```

But a problem occurs when we want to do dynamic dispatch, i.e. be able to pass in multiple implementations of the Context (usually for testing), and when the Context itself depends on another Context.  E.g.

```
trait MethodsNeedContext[Context] {
  def method1(p1: Int)(implicit context: Context): Int
}

object ExampleUsage {
  def callsMethod1(implicit contextWithContext: MethodsNeedContext[???], contextsContext: ???): Unit = {
    contextWithContext.method1(10)(contextsContext)
  }
}
```

We only know the type `???` at runtime, not at compile time.  The OOP way would be to make `MethodsNeedContext` an `abstract class`, then we can use an existential type. E.g.

```
abstract class OOPWay[Context <: ContextTypeBound](context: Context) {
  def method1(p1: Int): Int = context.send("hello world")
}

object ExampleUsage2 {
  def callsMethod1(implicit contextWithContext: OOPWay[_ <: ContextTypeBound]): Unit = {
    contextWithContext.method1(10)
  }
}
```

But if we wrap the `contextWithContext` and `contextContext` into a case class, then add an `implicit class` then we can solve the problem.  Full example below:

```
trait ContextTypeBound

trait MethodsNeedContext[Context <: ContextTypeBound] {
  def method1(p1: Int)(implicit ctx: Context): Int
  def method2(p2: String)(implicit ctx: Context): String
}

case class MethodsWithContext[T <: ContextTypeBound](methods: MethodsNeedContext[T], context: T)

object Pimps {
  implicit class PimpedMethodsWithContext[T <: ContextTypeBound](methods: MethodsWithContext[T]) {
    def method1(p1: Int): Int = methods.methods.method1(p1)(methods.context)
  }
}

import Pimps.PimpedMethodsWithContext

case class FooContext(foo: Int) extends ContextTypeBound

object FooExample extends MethodsNeedContext[FooContext] {
  def method1(p1: Int)(implicit ctx: FooContext): Int = ???
  def method2(p2: String)(implicit ctx: FooContext): String = ???
}

case class BobContext(foo: Int) extends ContextTypeBound

object BobExample extends MethodsNeedContext[BobContext] {
  def method1(p1: Int)(implicit ctx: BobContext): Int = ???
  def method2(p2: String)(implicit ctx: BobContext): String = ???
}

object ExampleUsage {
  def callsMethod1(implicit contextWithContext: MethodsWithContext[_ <: ContextTypeBound]): Unit = {
    contextWithContext.method1(10)
  }

  callsMethod1(MethodsWithContext(FooExample, FooContext(20)))
  // Does not compile
  callsMethod1(MethodsWithContext(BobExample, FooContext(20)))
}
```

My question(s) are:

1. Does this pattern have a name? Is it a standard Scala practice?
2. Is this a Scala only thing, or do other FP languages have similar mechanisms to do the same thing?  If other FP languages have different mechanisms, what are they?

Comment: If you want to use dynamic dispatch, the standard Scala practice is probably to use OOP as well, with a `trait` and multiple implementations for it. Your case class that explicitly puts context and methods together again seems to be a roundabout way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: For a new take on DI, also have a look at ZLayers from the ZIO project. https://zio.dev/docs/howto/howto_use_layers

Comment: Yes this approach is "roundabout" @Thilo but I prefer it to coupling scope to methods.

Comment: referential transparency means expressions do the exact same thing anywhere in the code.  I guess I'd call this scope transparency - everything the method needs gets injected in the params.  Scope transparency means methods do the exact same thing anywhere they are placed in the code.

Comment: You may like ZIO then. It puts the scope into the type of the expression. Your method one would be a `def method1(p1: Int) : ZIO[Context, Nothing, Int]`, saying that it requires `Context`, returns an `Int` and cannot fail.

Comment: And for your two different implementations, you could then either decide to expose that you need specifically a `BobContext` or a `FooContext`, or hide them behind a service trait (of which you can have a Bob and a Foo implementation, each of which will require the appropriate context upon construction) so that you can then dynamically dispatch between them.

Comment: Just a general note: In FP you don't need existential types that often. You usually use ad-hoc/parametric polymorphism (which is static) and higher order functions.